# rdkit produces two different images using MolToFile() and displaying in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, display, rdkit

I am generating an image of a molecule using rdkit in Python.
Using `from IPython.display import display` and `display(mol)` produces the output image I need.
However, when I try saving it using Draw.MolToFile(mol, 'mol.png'), I get an image with incorrect bonds and missing elements.

Is there a way to save the displayed image from Jupyter into a file? I have a few hundred elements, so using 'Save as...' would take too long.

Comment: I tried it with a bunch of molecules and the saved images are correct. What version of RDKit do you use? What is your input (e.g. SMILES or Molfile)? Could you provide some code with a sample molecule?